# Android heap dump convert to J2SE : hprof-conv: command not found

Tags: java, android, memory-management, hprof, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Following [this](https://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk?t=29m50s) guide from Patrick Dubroy, i try to convert my heap dump to J2SE HPROF, but can't execute an `hprof-conv`. And that's strange because it located in folder.

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excute absolute path

```
    ~/Document/dev_env/android/platform-tools/hprof-conv
```

or if your current path is "~/Document/dev_env/android/platform-tools" like your screenshot

```
    ./hprof-conv
```

You can execute `hprof-conv`.